# JSP and Postgres, how to fill a table?

Tags: jsp, html-table

I have a database written in Postgresql. I want that my database with all its columnms and rows are shown in my browser. Therefore I am using JSP. In the browser one can just see the column names. There is no information saved in. See Screenshot for further. The problem is that I do not know how to fill my database VIA JSP using html codes for filling a table. Can anyone help me please. This is my screen of the current database. As you can see, there are no information. The table is empty.

[image: Screenshot 1]

This is my JSP Code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"
import="java.sql.* "%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Films Example: JSP</title>
 </head>
<body bgcolor="white">
   <div>
    <h1>Movies</h1>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td>imdbID</td>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>year</td>
            <td>rating</td>
            <td>votes</td>
            <td>runtime</td>
            <td>actors</td>
            <td>genres</td>
            <td>directors</td>
        </tr>

        <%
            try {
                String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
                String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/movie";
                String username = "postgres";
                String password = "mypassword";
                String myDataField = null;
                String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM movie";
                Connection myConnection = null;
                PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = null;
                ResultSet myResultSet = null;
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                myPreparedStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
                myResultSet = myPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
                out.println("<table border=1>");
                while (myResultSet.next()) {
                    String imdbID = myResultSet.getString("imdbID");
                    String name = myResultSet.getString("name");
                    int year = myResultSet.getInt("year");
                    double rating = myResultSet.getDouble("rating");
                    int votes = myResultSet.getInt("votes");
                    int runtime = myResultSet.getInt("runtime");
                    String directors = myResultSet.getString("directors");
                    out.println("<tr><td>" + imdbID + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + year + "</td><td>" + rating
                            + "</td><td>" + votes + "</td> <td>" + runtime + "</td> <td>" + directors + "</td> </tr>");
                }
                out.println("</table>");

                myConnection.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                out.print("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
                out.print("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
                out.print("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            }
        %>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First close the scriptlet thag before **out.println("<table>");** and after that write  **<table>** and inside  using **expression tag** wirte you code. It will definitely print your table.

You can also write seperate **java class** file for you **database connection** and return **List** object through that class to the jsp in the form of **session** or **request/response** object. This is the best way  instead of writing whole code in your jsp page. Try it and iterate that object using **foreach** loop.

Comment: what do you mean by "scriptlet" , sorry english is not my mother tongue :D. Second question: "write your code" what code ? from postgres? what do you mean by code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **out.println("<table border=1>");** and
**out.println("</table>");** from your JSP program and then run it. It will work. Try it.